# How to find a specific element of a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following list:

```
{{0.1, 5}, {0.3, 18}, {0.4, 6}, {0.7, 9}, {1.1, 5}}
```

I want to obtain the second element of a sub-list with respect to the first element of the sub-list.

for example: given 0.4 I would like to retrieve 6, given 0.1 I would like to retrieve 5.

The first element in the sub-lists are monotonically increasing and non repetitive.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Kuba, now there are many things to try and to learn from. best

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two possible examples (say for example you are interested in 0.1, but it works with any entry):

```
list = {{0.1, 5}, {0.3, 18}, {0.4, 6}, {0.7, 9}, {1.1, 5}};
Cases[list, {0.1, _}]
Select[list, #[[1]] == 0.1 &]
```

Edit: if you only want the second element, go for:

```
Cases[list, {0.1, _}][[1, 2]]
Select[list, #[[1]] == 0.1 &][[1, 2]]
```

Comment: Consider also `Cases[list, {0.1, b_} -> b]` to return only the second element of each sublist.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach is to convert your `List` to an `Association`:

```
list = {{0.1, 5}, {0.3, 18}, {0.4, 6}, {0.7, 9}, {1.1, 5}};
arse = AssociationThread @@ Transpose@list;
arse[0.4] (* 6 *)
arse[0.1] (* 5 *)
```

This assumes that each `Key` (each first element of a pair) are unique, but otherwise your question would be ill-posed.

Comment: Please, don't call associations that way... ;)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Aah, I was going to ask for explanations (like it's a bad habit to call "association[something]`). Then I got it :D I'll edit to raise the ambiguity ;)

Comment: Not sure wether that is better... =D

Comment: It raises the ambiguity!

Answer (score 4):

Given that you only want the second element, and there are no repeats, you could use `FirstCase`

```
secondElement[firstElement_] := 
 FirstCase[{firstElement, other_} :> other]

secondElement[.1]@{{0.1, 5}, {0.3, 18}, {0.4, 6}, {0.7, 9}, {1.1, 5}}
(* 5 *)

secondElement[0.4]@{{0.1, 5}, {0.3, 18}, {0.4, 6}, {0.7, 9}, {1.1, 5}}
(* 6 *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Pick [#[[All, 2]], #[[All, 1]], 0.4] &@lst
```

> {6}

```
Pick [#[[All, 2]], #[[All, 1]], 0.1] &@lst
```

> {5}

```
Pick [#[[All, 2]], #[[All, 1]], 0.1 | 0.4] &@lst
```

> {5, 6}